# What size are the denizens from "Shadows of the apt"?

Tags: shadows-of-the-apt

In the Tchaikovsky "Shadows of the apt" series people share certain characteristics with insects: fly-kinden are small, agile and restless, ant-kinden are natural born soldiers etc. Later on we meet people connected to ocean animals like crabs or jellyfish bit never someone related to let's say dogs, cats or horses (actually "giant" beatles work as beasts of burden). Furthermore the technology uses solutions that would work with a very small scale world - winded spring cars or planes, deadly BB guns...

So is there any inclination what size are people leaving in this world? Are they similar size to us or maybe the whole story takes place near some small pond?

Update to the question (based on @Valorum quotes):

- The fact that author compares size of various things in book to similar things in our reality ("big as a horse",  "eighteen inches long") would suggest that people living in the "Shadows" series are normal size (more or less, depending on the specie). But those can be used figuratively, for the benefit of the reader.
- Other facts seems to suggest that they are insect size: Some species can fly using wings, spring wind-up devices are strong enough to power planes, air-powered guns are more deadly than gunpowder - of course this can be handwaved as "magic" or "magical technology".

Comment: Although to be honest I don't really remember normal size insects mentioned - there were a few giant ones (like the beatles used as horses)

Comment: No i don't : there are mentioned horses or our units if measurements but it all can be done for readers benefit and used figuratively. There are just quite a few things that would make sense only if the people living there were tiny - in example the fact they can fly using own wings

Answer (score 2):

**The insect-Kinden appear to be various sizes, but all on a human scale, ranging from about three feet high, up to about seven.**

> *She saw it was their captain, Amnon, who had always terrified her. **He was over six foot – very tall for a Beetle** – but he seemed at least a foot taller still.*
>
> <sub><sup>The Scarab Path</sup></sub>

and

> *And the day after, Sperra [a fly-Kinden] had been sent for by the
> Queen. So **here she was, a woman of three foot nine inches,** in plain
> and darned clothes, appearing before the Royal Court of Sarn.*
>
> <sub><sup>Dragonfly Falling</sup></sub>

and

> *There was no time to wonder. **Another Scorpion-kinden thundered past,
> another giant. They were all at least seven feet tall for sure.***
>
> <sub><sup>The Scarab Path</sup></sub>

**We see various objects described in inches. Again, these are consistent with a human scale.**

> *More light struck the vast dagger of earth and stone, turning it the
> colour of honey. **It was a hundred feet high, perhaps more,** for the
> scale of the buildings in its shadow was hard to guess. Che had a
> strange feeling in her stomach at the sight which, after some
> hesitation, she identified as excitement.*
>
> <sub><sup>The Scarab Path</sup></sub>

and

> *Che did not hesitate. Even as the dark figure turned she was on him,
> having instantly drawn **the knife she carried everywhere for
> protection. It was a tiny thing, barely four inches of blade**, but she
> raked it savagely across his back.*
>
> <sub><sup>Empire in Black and Gold</sup></sub>

and

> *‘In Collegium, kept in a certain private collection, there is this
> item. **A box, no more than six inches to a side.** Unopenable, or at
> least you are apparently advised not to open it.*
>
> <sub><sup>Dragonfly Falling</sup></sub>

**Interestingly, insect-scale insects also seem to exist in the world as well**

> *Now all she had to do was to prise open her mind sufficiently to allow
> the enveloping perfection of that Ideal into her life, and to accept
> its gifts. And yet her mind still battered against the recent past
> **like a fly at a window pane.***
>
> <sub><sup>Empire in Black and Gold</sup></sub>

and

> *‘Tried.’ She shrugged. ‘They broke out the Chneuma five nights ago,
> and now we’re all **buzzing about inside our own heads like flies in a
> bottle.***
>
> <sub><sup>Seal of the Worm</sup></sub>

and

> *They splashed on through clear, shallow water for a moment, then there
> was plantlife all around, more mud underfoot, and **a fog of gnats that
> seemed almost solid.***
>
> <sub><sup>Heirs of the Blade</sup></sub>